# jquery don't get the real height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, height

I am trying to find out why jquery can't return the actual heigth of the jquery-mobile header, see this screenshot: http://i43.tinypic.com/21epavn.png, the header is 42px high, and jquery returns

```
>$('body').find('div[data-role=header]').css('height') 
"40px"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The padding is not included in `.height()`. Use `.outerHeight()` instead.

Comment: @Rob W ~ `.outerHeight()` includes padding, yes, but also border width (and optionally, margin). If you're only interested in including padding, use `.innerHeight()`.

Comment: height -> 40px, innerHeight -> 40px, outerHeight -> 42px  (header div has border: 1px solid #456F9A; , no margin, no padding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing (could be wrong, but my first thought...) that the height of the element is 40px, and then it has a 1px margin/padding/border wrapped around it. Try specifying the following in your CSS:

```
div[data-role=header] {margin:0;border:0;padding:0}
```

and see if you still have this problem?

According to Rob W, there is a .outerHeight() function in jQuery which will include the padding in its calculation. Consider using that instead if you don't want to remove your padding.